# Font Hinting in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, display, fonts

I'm in the process of switching from 12.04 to 14.04 on all of my machines.

I'm a bit particular about font rendering and used the app "unsettings" to set font hinting to None on 12.04. However, it seems like I can't install unsettings on 14.04.

Does anyone know a way to manipulate the way text is rendered on 14.04?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried testing using unsettings in 14.04 in a VM, to see if it can be got to work (perhaps after editing the sources for apt-get)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Infinality](http://www.infinality.net/blog/). Detailed installation instructions are available [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/better-font-rendering-in-linux-with.html).

Answer (score 2):

Load Unity tweak or Gnome Tweak - they'll provide the needed dialog box.

```
unity-tweak-tool
gnome-tweak-tool
```

I had to turn off hinting with 14.10. Theres a bug, not well understood.

Comment: Well there do seem to be bugs, but in my case its bad hardware. The rule is:  ' always assume software is at fault esp right after a big change' until it really **is** bad hardware.